# Find correct string in string

Tags: javascript

i have string:

```
<em>hhhhhhhhhhhhh gggggggggggg hhhhhhhhhhh</em> <strong>hhhhhhhhhh hhhhhhhhh hhhhhhhhh</strong> gggggggggg ggggggg hhhhhhhhhhh ggggggggggggggggggggggggg <em>ggggggg ggggggg <strong>gggggggg dddddddddd</strong></em>
```

And now i wont find :

```
var regex = /<em>(.*?)<\/strong><\/em>/g;
var spr = string.match(regexxx);
alert(spr.toString());
```

This prints my full string.

```
<em>hhhhhhhhhhhhh gggggggggggg hhhhhhhhhhh</em> <strong>hhhhhhhhhh hhhhhhhhh hhhhhhhhh</strong> gggggggggg ggggggg hhhhhhhhhhh ggggggggggggggggggggggggg <em>ggggggg ggggggg <strong>gggggggg dddddddddd</strong></em>
```

And sure this is good. 
But this is not what i want!
I want this:

```
<em>ggggggg ggggggg <strong>gggggggg dddddddddd</strong></em>
```

Regex must find everything between:

```
<em>...</strong></em>
```

but not if between

```
<em>..**</em>**.</strong></em> .
```

This is not correct:

```
<em>testestest</em>test test</strong></em>
```

This is good:

```
<em>test<strong>test test</strong></em>
```

What regular expression do I use to do this?

Comment: [Obligatory](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1223693)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your regex. If you want to access what is inside the `<em>` and `<strong>` elements just add `()`  around the `[^<]` section of the regex.

```
var regex = /<em>[^<]*?<strong>[^<]*?<\/strong><\/em>/g;
var result = regex.exec(s)
console.log(result[0]);
```

This print :

```
<em>ggggggg ggggggg <strong>gggggggg dddddddddd</strong></em>
```